# UITableViewCell background color based upon NSFetchedResultsController - strange issues

Tags: ios5, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is driving me absolutely insane.

I have a UITableView with cells populated via an NSFetchedResultsController that should have their background color set based upon one of the Core Data parameters.

This table view is in the master view of a UISplitViewController and the selected cell needs to remain visibly selected to indicate what is being displayed in the detail view.

Based upon guidance from several other Stack Overflow questions, I have learned that the ideal place to configure the cell is during the willDisplayCell delegate call, like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
WorkTask *workTask = (WorkTask*) [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([workTask.strStatus isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"fffdcf"]; 
    // cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"fffdcf"];
    // cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"fffdcf"];

} else if ([workTask.strStatus isEqualToString:@"B"]) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"cfffd1"];
    // cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"cfffd1"];
    // cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"cfffd1"];

} else if ([workTask.strStatus isEqualToString:@"C"]) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"ffcfcf"];
    // cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"ffcfcf"];
    // cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"ffcfcf"];
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"ffffff"];
    // cell.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;
}
```

This mostly sort of works.  But...

Depending on how I play around with different variants of accomplishing this, I end up with the background color being ignored sometimes (and only sometimes?!?) behind the textLabel and detailTextLabel. Or causing the cell to display incorrectly while selected.  Or having the checkmark indicator displayed without a background color. Or having new items added to the core data database showing up in the table, but with the no background color for the cell, but the text labels having a background color.

No matter what I do, I have not found a simple and intuitive way to make things behave overall as expected - particularly when cells are being programmatically selected.

In fact - the cell selection seems like it might be at the root of the problem. The selected cell is usually the one that ends up drawn incorrectly after I change the selection to another, particularly if the color of the cell changed while the cell was selected.

Is there any example out there anywhere of how this is supposed to work?!?!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried assigning a `cell.selectedBackgroundView` and `cell.backgroundView` ? This seems to fix a lot of problem with the cell selection.

Comment: I would override `-setHighlighted:` (in your cell subclass)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would create a `UITableViewCell` subclass with your own `titleLabel/subtitleLabel` UILabels in it and stop using the textLabel/detailTextLabel. In the xib file you can just change the background color of the labels and of the cell. I have never had the sort of problem you are experiencing when I have used custom cells as opposed to the default cells.

Here's an example of how to load a UITableViewCell from an xib:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.titleLabel.text = @"whatever";
    cell.subtitleLabel.text = @"whatever";

    return cell;
}
```

You could also try setting the background color of the cell's contentView.

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = ...;
```

If you really can't figure it out, then in a UITableViewCell subclass you could always just put a UIView of your own in the background of the cell and change the background color of that view instead.

`willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` might not get called after `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` is called (i.e. when you add items into core data w/ a fetchedresultscontroller). If absolutely necessary maybe you should try setting the background color of the cell and it's contentView in both `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: "In the xib file you can just change the background color of the labels and of the cell." -- The catch is that I am changing the background color dynamically based upon an attribute managed by Core Data. Returning a configured cell is easy enough - having the color change properly on the fly is the problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: I still think trying out a custom cell is worth a shot. You could still change the background color in willDisplayCell: and possibly event in cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: I'll try out changing things around to use a custom cell, and will report back here.  Meanwhile, the bounty is yours for lack of a better answer from anyone else. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

For some bizarre reason the background color of UITableViewCell objects can only be set just before the cell is drawn. In your UITableView's delegate implement this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Set the background color of the cell there and it will draw the way you want.